# Fetch data from database to display in view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to fetch the data from database using the session id but i just don't know how to do it.

here is my controller

```
    public function index(){
    $data['title'] = 'My Profile';
    $data['content'] = 'profile';
    $data['singel_user'] = $this->user_model->get_user_byid($this->session->userdata('u_id'));
    $this->load->view('layout/admin_layout', $data);
```

and in my model

```
//returns specific data from users
public function get_user_byid($u_id) {
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id ='$u_id'");
    return $q->result();
}
```

How can I display the specific data to the view page?

Comment: Please read tutorial here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codeigniter when you pass variables under `$data` variable in view they can be accessed simple as `$variable`. Example, in your case `$data['singel_user']` can be accessed as `$singel_user` inside your `admin_layout.php` view.

Try to write `print_r($singel_user);` in your `admin_layout.php`  and you will see whole variable structure returned from database.

Comment: <?php print_r($single_user); ?> I tried this but is says undefined variable single_user

Comment: there's a typo in your controller `$data['singel_user']` singel*, not single. That's why in my answer there's `$singel_user` everythere

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 if(!empty($single)){
 foreach($single as $key=>$result) {?>
    <?php echo $result->id; ?>
<?php } } ?>
```